# Show that the integral $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(E_0-V(y))}}dy=\infty.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics, quantum-mechanics

This is exercise 2.2(b) in Brian Hall's **Quantum Theory for Mathematicians**.

> Given a continuously differentiable potential energy function $V:{\bf
>  R}\rightarrow{\bf R}$.
>
> Suppose that $V(x)<E_0$ for $x_0\leq x<x_1$, with $V(x_1)=E_0$ and
>   $V'(x_1)=0$.
>
> Show that,
>
> $$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(E_0-V(y))}}dy=\infty.$$

I spent a while trying to unsuccessfully prove this, and began to suspect it was in fact not true.

Here is the counterexample I came up with:

Let $E_0=1$ and consider the following potential energy function on the interval $[0,1]$,

$$V(x)=-(x-1)^\frac{4}{3}+1.$$

Then $V(x) < E_0$ on $[0,1)$ with $V(x_1)=E_0$, and $V'(x_1)=-\frac{4}{3}(x_1-1)^\frac{1}{3}=0$.

Observe that the integral is finite,

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(1+(y-1)^\frac{4}{3}-1)}}dy=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_0^1\frac{1}{(y-1)^\frac{2}{3}}dy=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}3(y-1)^\frac{1}{3}\Biggr\rvert_{0}^1=3\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}.$$

Am I missing something here? Is the exercise really incorrect as stated?

I'm aware of the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1410004/26920), however it's too handwavy for me to follow.

**Edit:**

$\color{blue}{\text{Since my counterexample is not smooth, I suspect that maybe I need to assume that the}}$ 
$\color{blue}{\text{potential $V$ is smooth for this to be true.}}$

If I assume that $V$ is smooth, could anyone give me some help on how to use this fact to solve this?

Comment: I assume $x_0\le0<x_1$ should read $x_0\le x<x_1$.

Comment: @J.G. fixed, thanks

Comment: Regarding your edit: on $[0,\,1]$, $V=1-(1-x)^{4/3}\implies V^\prime=\frac43(1-x)^{1/3}$, which is continuous on the interval, i.e. $V$ is continuously differentiable. So the problem statement accepts this choice of $V$, Perhaps it's meant to say *twice* continuously differentiable.

Comment: From the wording of the problem, I think you are correct that the problem is false.  The potential $V$ needs to be something stronger than just continuously differentiable.  Being twice continuously differentiable or smooth will suffice, of course.

Comment: @J.G. I suspect that $V$ may be required to be smooth, although it isn't stated specifically in the exercise, the potential energy is mentioned as being smooth in the chapter's discussion.